# Comparing two generics in compareTo()

Tags: java, generics, comparable, compareto

I have the following class signatures:

```
public class SkipListSet<T extends Comparable<T>> implements SortedSet<T>
```

and another class outside of SkipListSet class:

```
class Node<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

The second one acts as a wrapper class that contains the following:

```
        T data;
        List<Node<T>> tower;
        Node<T> nextNode = null;
        Node<T> prevNode = null;
```

When I try implementing compareTo() method in my Node class:

```
        public int compareTo(T somePayLoad) {
            if (this.data < somePayLoad)
                return -1;
            else if (this.data > somePayLoad)
                return 1;
            else
                return 0;
        }
```

I get the following error:

```
SkipListSet.java:171: error: bad operand types for binary operator '<'
                        if (this.data < somePayLoad)
                                      ^
  first type:  T
  second type: T
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Comparable<T> declared in class SkipListSet.Node
```

Why is it that I can't compare two types of T data in my compareTo method?

Comment: `<` is only used for numbers in Java. As `T` is comparable, you can rather use `if (this.data.compareTo(somePayLoad) < 0)`

Answer (score 2):

You can't use '<' or '>' on objects. I think what you need is:

```
public int compareTo(T somePayLoad) {

    return this.data.compareTo(somePayLoad.data);
}
```

(Add null checks).

Comment: So PayLoad is not an object. It is a T type of data. I want to compare two T types of data, T data and T PayLoad

Comment: It is still an object. what you call "T type of data" is actually "object of type T".

Comment: You don't have to implement `compareTo(T)`. Because the type `T` already implements `Compare<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write the compareTo method.
T class should implement Comparable inteface.

```
    TestSkipListSet<NodeData> list = new TestSkipListSet<NodeData>();
    TestSkipListSet<NodeData2> list2 = new TestSkipListSet<NodeData2>();
```

```
    class NodeData implements Comparable<NodeData> {
        int value;
        @Override
        public int compareTo(@NonNull NodeData o) {
            return this.value - o.value;
        }
    }
```

```
    class NodeData2 implements Comparable<NodeData2> {
        TestUser value;
        @Override
        public int compareTo(@NonNull NodeData2 o) {
            return this.value.age-o.value.age;
        }
    }
    class TestUser{
        int age;
    }
```

```
    public class TestSkipListSet<T extends Comparable<T>> implements SortedSet<T>{
       ...
    }
```